# How to put a word into a var

Tags: c++, struct, cin, cout, cpu-word

I would like to set a program that ask personnal information to a "customer", and this code need to store a name and a surname in a structure contening al the var.
But at the output it shows me a number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//DECLARATIONS

struct dates {
int emb_date;
int post_date;
};

struct info {
int nom;
int prenom;
};

void saisie_info() {
info identite;
cout << "Veuillez indiquer votre prenom : " << endl;
cin >> identite.prenom;
cout << "Veuiller maintenant insiquer votre nom : " << endl;
cin >> identite.nom;
cout << identite.prenom << " " << identite.nom << endl;
}

int main()
{
saisie_info();
}
```

As you can see : prenom mean Surname, and nom mean Name (I'm french)
And that don't work....
Why ?
I precise I have no other choice to use a '''struct''' to store "nom" and "prenom".
Thanks for your help

Comment: what is the meaning of "don't work" ? What does the code do? What should it do instead? What is input, output, expected output?

Comment: The code is "ok". I mean for someone named 46303 with sursame 5818 there is no problem. Why is `prenom` and `nom` integers?

Comment: Are you familiar with `string`s? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_strings.htm

Comment: "_his code need to store a name and a surname in a structure contening al the var. But at the output it shows me a number._" If you need to store a name, or a surname, why are you reading those into an `int`, which represents `integer`?

Comment: what is strange is that if you get numbers as output that means you also must have entered numbers as input...

Comment: @idclev463035818 My code is sensed to receive a word and to store it into a variable

Comment: your code reads integers and prints integers. Use `std::string` if you want to read and display strings

Comment: @Céleste Once again, if you need to read a word, why did you declare your variables with an `int` type, instead of `std::string`?

Comment: To all of you, I just don't know how to do, I only know that "nom" and "prenom" are words, and that I have to store them into a variable, what I don't know wich type of variable I have to use

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thank You, I'll try that

Comment: Did you try [reading a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to find out what kind of variable types exists in C++ and how they are used?

Comment: Oh thanks !! It works with strings, It seems so obvious I'm a bit stupid sorry. Have a nice day.

Comment: please do not add "SOLVED" to your question. The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept one of the answers

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Because I started C++ yesterday :) I don't really know actually what do what in a code.

Comment: C++ isnt the best language to learn via guessing. Sam gave you a link to a large collection of books, you should get one

Comment: @idclev463035818 I take all your consel, and I will improve myself thanks to them. And yes I saw what Sam gave. But how do I "accept" an answer

Comment: not sure anymore but this should have been part of the [tour]

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ew I missed that. I'll read it

Comment: @Céleste "_Because I started C++ yesterday_" You can't learn C++ by guessing, as already explained by others. Mostly because it is easy to write code, which has undefined behavior, and seems to work by sheer coincidence, which then breaks after unrelated changes are made. By the very nature of undefined behavior - it is impossible to test (without knowing it) if some behavior is undefined.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I don't only do by guessing, hopefuly. But I can't know what I don't know. That's why I ask here, so I can have a precise answer to my precise problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the data type of `nom` and `prenom` in the `struct info`. The type `int` represents numbers. Strings (or words) are represented by `std::string` in C++:

```
struct info {
    std::string nom;
    std::string prenom;
};
```

If I make that change to your code and I enter my name, I see it in the output.